# Задание: Поставить Virtual Box, запустить на нем MS-DOS и с него пингануть выданный ip

Tags: windows, virtualbox

MS-DOS вижу впервые, прошу помощи у мастеров, как пошагово выполнить данное задание.

Comment: Так а в чем конкретно сложность возникла?

Comment: Просто ввести команду ping нельзя, необходимо установить соотвествующие утилиты для MS-DOS, настроить интернет соединение (Как я понял), а как это сделать - не знаю.

Comment: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/901/how-can-ms-dos-be-installed-on-virtualbox

Comment: Или вот ещё: https://lagovskiy.ru/blog/view/install-ms-dos-6-22-in-virtualbox/

Comment: Берите FreeDOS, там все нужное по идее есть. Вот статья по настройке сети: http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/Networking_FreeDOS_-_Quick_Networking_HowTo

Answer (score 0):

Да все просто, найти MSDOS, установить, узнать какая сетевая карта, найти драйвера к ней, установить, найти сетевой клиент, установить, там должен быть ping, но подключить сетевой диск или что-то открыть в сети вряд ли получится, может с XP.

Comment: Virtual box установил, MS-DOS в него поставил, запустил. Передо мной теперь терминал, что дальше - не знаю. Тут просто сразу оговорюсь, опыта работы в терминале мало, MS-DOS как писал вышел - вижу впервые. Информация в интернете по моему вопросу вроде и есть, но она не структурированна, и мне мало, что понятно.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста, объяснить мне пошагово, что найти, что скачать и как установить.

Comment: Я не знаю где найти дрова, dos на сетевую карту vbox, на настоящую можно найти у производителя, но думаю сейчас это тяжело.

Comment: Само задание специфическое, а как через VB в MS-DOS выйти в интернет, понятия не имею.

Comment: что такое "выйти в интернет"?

Comment: @Сергей, то есть VB тоже досовский? Какая там версия, 1.0 была, с окошками псевдографикой?

Comment: Предполагаю что версия ниже чем MS-DOS 6.22 с сетью работать не будет, в DOS ни каких окошек нет.

Comment: Нет, на свою рабочую операционную систему Linux, я поставил VirtualBox 6.1. В программе VirtualBox создал виртуальный образ MS-DOS, закончил установку, и передо мной появился терминал,

"Выйти в интернет" - Имею ввиду, что мне необходимо как-то предоставить доступ MS-DOS доступ в интернет, чтобы была возможность пингануть ip и выполнить задание. 

А я даже не понимаю как пользоваться MS-DOS, передо мной просто терминал и все. Даже не понял как Volkov Comander на него установить.